# Android google sign-in failed only aab file case

Tags: android, google-signin, android-app-bundle

I am developing an android app with Google sign-in.

But the google sign-in is failing with 10 error code.

I found that it is related with signing settings.

I checked about this, but I cannot find any wrong things.

When I build the app as .aab file using below command:

```
# gradlew clean bundeRelease
```

The google sign-in is failed with 10 error code.

But when I build the app as .apk file using below command:

```
# gradlew clean assembleRelease
```

The google sign-in success!

I don't know what happened...

What difference???

---

One more thing that I found is...

In general, we cannot install the `.aab` file directly.

So I used "Firebase App Distribution".

In case of `.apk` file, I just copy it into my phone directly, and installed it.

But in case of `.aab` file, I upload it into "Firebase App Distribution", and download & install.

I did one more test.

Actually, my app is already released on the PlayStore.
So I upload the `.aab` file into the PlayStore "Internal Test Process".
And when I download & install from the "Internal test", the Google sign-in works fine!

In summary,

- I built 2 file: `.apk`, `.aab`
- `.apk` always works fine (Goole Sign-in)
- PlayStore (Internal Test) - `.aab` works fine
- Firebase App Distribution - `.aab` didn't work (10 error)

Comment: Is this only on local development?

Comment: I run the both command on my desktop.

Answer (score 0):

This is a signing issue.

The AAB is not what gets installed on the device, there is an additional step that will convert AABs into APKs, and those APKs are signed. You have to ensure that the signing key those APKs are signed with are registered in your Google API Console: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

Since it works with the Play Store, I assume you have registered your app signing key (from "Play Signing") in the Google API Console, but you haven't done so with the key that Firebase App Distribution signs your APKs with.

Regarding the AAB failing locally, we're missing some information: you're saying how you build the app bundle but not how you build the APKs that you deploy to the device from that app bundle. As I mentioned, what's important is the signing key that is used to sign those APKs. Make sure that the certificate associated with that keystore is also registered in the Google API Console for the Google Sign-in API (see link above).

Answer (score 0):

Google login error 10 is typically an issue with the wrong key being used to sign your app or the OAuth client ID for the key you are using not being registered with Google Cloud Console.

If you are creating a development version of your app (probably a .apk file) then you are likely using the default debug keystore that comes when you instal the android SDK on you box. On macOS that's located at `~/.android/debug.keystore`. In this case you have to create a SHA1 fingerprint of that keystore using `keytool`

```
keytool -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -list -v

SHA1: 00:11:22:33:44:55:66:77:88:99:AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF:00:11:22:33:44
```

You copy this value and use it to create a new OAuth client ID that uses it inside Google Cloud Console.

If you are creating a release version of your app and you're managing the app signing keys yourself, you'll do the same thing but using the release key and few extra parameters for passwords:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore /path/to/release.keystore -storepass <password> -keypass <password>
```

If you are using Google Play App Signing then you Google manages the release keys for you so you won't have access to them to create the SHA1 fingerprint. In this case, Google gives you access to it through the Google Play Console (currently that's under Setup > App Integrity > App Signing tab). Once you have it, you can use it to create the OAuth client ID like above.

Comment: For me, Google SignIn is working for a debug build and also when srunning a release build (signed with own keystore) on device/emulator. But when uploading an aab to Google Play internal testing, I always get this code 10 error.
I created another Android OAuth client id in cloud console with the SHA1-fingerprint from app signing section in Google Play console. I double checked that the package name is correct.
Do you have an idea what else could be wrong?

Comment: never mind, I just found out that there is a separate SHA-fingerprint section for internal testing in Google Play Console, so I had to add another OAuth client ID in cloud console, now it is working